# When to use viewDataBinding.invalidateAll()

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I was trying to see when `binding.invalidateAll()` is needed to refresh the UI when the data changes.

I have 2 examples where I change the data, in one of them the UI data changes automatically and in the other, I need to use `invalidateAll()` to see the changes

First of all, below is the XML of the `TextView` I'm testing on:

```
        ...
 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{mainActivity.myName.name}" />
```

**First Example**

In the first example, if I change the data inside `onCreate()` or `onResume()` the data changes directly without the need for `invalidateAll()`, please find the code below:

```
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    var myName = MyName(name = "Test")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.mainActivity = this;

        myName.name = "Data is visible directly"
    }
```

Here, once the UI is drawn to the user, I see the TextView's text directly set as "Data is visible directly" without the need to call `binding.invalidateAll()`

**Second Example**

In the second example, I only change the text when a button is clicked as in the below code:

```
  ...

  fun onButtonClickedChangeData(view:View){
        myName.name = "Data is visible only after invalidateAll is called"
        binding.invalidateAll() // without it the text won't change
    }
```

In the second example, I have to use `binding.invalidateAll()` for the text of the TextView to change, if I don't use `invalidateAll()` the text will not change.

**My First Speculation (which seems to be wrong)**

I first thought maybe `binding.invalidateAll()` is needed when we change the data while the activity is already running and the UI is already visible to the user, and that `invalidateAll()` won't be needed if the data changes before the UI is drawn yet to the user (giving that the UI is only visible to the user in `onResumue()` according to my knowledge).

But when I tried to update the data inside `onResumue()` the data changed directly as well without the need for `binding.invalidateAll()`

Comment: Hi @Yousef Gamal Can't you just use `executePendingBindings()` instead of `invalidateAll()`?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#executependingbindings

Comment: Hi @nuhkoca Thank you for mentioning `executePendingBindings()`, I haven't used it before, but I'll try it out. But it's still honestly interesting to know why sometimes `invalidateAll()` is needed and other times it's not to update the UI

Comment: 1 - Databinding isn't magic - it generates code you can put breakpoints in trace for yourself when binding happens. 2. if you make your variables that you bind (like "name") `LiveData` or `Observable`, then you don't need `invalidateAll()` (which is a shotgun approach).